# How to get a SUM of grouped COUNT in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a SUM of a grouped Count.

my table result is like this.

```
ID | Name | count
1     k        5
2     k        4
3     a        12
```

I want a result lik this.

```
ID | Name | count
 1     k        9
 3     a        12
```

These is my real query.

```
SELECT COUNT( clubs_messages.id_user ) AS nbr, users.name, users.id, users.email
FROM users
JOIN clubs_messages ON users.id = clubs_messages.id_user
GROUP BY clubs_messages.id_user
UNION 
SELECT 'SUM' users.name, COUNT( clubs_messages.id_user ) 
FROM users
JOIN clubs_messages ON users.id = clubs_messages.id_user
```

So any help please. Thanks

Comment: Can you recheck your desired result?  is it `2-a-12` or `3-a-12` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just have to GROUP BY Name instead of user_id. Check the following query

```
   SELECT COUNT( clubs_messages.id_user ) AS nbr, users.name
   FROM users
   JOIN clubs_messages ON users.id = clubs_messages.id_user
   GROUP BY users.name
```

Comment: but if id did this  `SELECT COUNT( clubs_messages.id_user ) AS nbr, users.name, users.id, users.email
 FROM users
 JOIN clubs_messages ON users.id = clubs_messages.id_user
 GROUP BY  users.id
UNION

SELECT COUNT( sessions_messages.id_user ) AS nbr, users.name, users.id, users.email
 FROM users
 JOIN sessions_messages ON users.id = sessions_messages.id_user
 GROUP BY  users.id` its have no effect

Comment: I didn't understand your comment but if you GROUP BY id you ask for grouping the rows with the same id. You need to count the rows with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are grouping by ID rather than by name:

```
SELECT COUNT( clubs_messages.id_user ) AS nbr, users.name, users.id, users.email
FROM users
JOIN clubs_messages ON users.id = clubs_messages.id_user
GROUP BY clubs_messages.id_user
```

To fix this, you'll need to group by name:

```
SELECT COUNT( clubs_messages.id_user ) AS nbr, users.name, users.id, users.email
FROM users
JOIN clubs_messages ON users.id = clubs_messages.id_user
GROUP BY users.name
```